# Which subtheme did the "Space Monorail" sets come under?

Tags: sets, theme, space, monorail

Many years ago I remeber attending a model railway exhibition and one of the railways was a Lego monorial that looked very "space" based. I've found 6990 (Monorail Transport System) and 6991 (Monorail Transport Base) but I can't find out what sub-theme they came under.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BrickSet lists [6990](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6990-1) under the [Futuron](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Space&subtheme=Futuron) space sub-theme and [6991](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6991-1) in the [Unitron](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Space&subtheme=Unitron) space sub-themes.

There was also a [Monorail](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Town&subtheme=Monorail) sub-theme of City.

Comment: Did not know about the City subtheme. Thanks!